# When I am zoom in an image it has to move with in boundaries when dragging with finger

Tags: java, android, xml

Please anyone provide XML and Java code for when I am zoom in an image with my two fingers after zoom it has to move with in boundaries when dragging with finger

Iam trying to drag an image with my finger but it is going from the screen but I want  that image only move with in screen after I zoom in that image then move only with in boundaries please anyone provide XML and Java code for this problem

For example if I zoomed an image with my two fingers on mobile screen after it needs to move when I drag with my finger only in screen area or layout area but it is moving completely from the screen or it's only zoomed in not moving